# When is minimizing the sum of images of $f$ equivalent to minimizing the sum of independent variables?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I have to admit I am not good at math, but this is a problem I am having trouble with.

> What kind of function $f$ can guarantee that
>
> $$\arg\min\sum_{i=1}^Kf(x_i) = \arg\min\sum_{i=1}^Kx_i$$

Thank you. Cost Function $f$ is not explicitly defined here, and so the problem cannot be solved as a normal optimization problem. $x_i$ here are some feasible solutions of a plan. We want to know on what condition can we reduce the problem to  $\min\sum_{i=1}^Kx_i$ so it can be solved.  For ${x_i}$ there is no explicit constraints between each other.

Comment: You likely need some constraints on the $x_i$. Do you want them to be nonnegative?

Comment: yes they are positive.

Comment: I think you still have an ill-defined problem. Because then the minimum is always 0...seems a bit uninteresting.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. i dont mean to solve the optimization problem, but wonder what property $f$ should have (e.g convex? increasing?)

Comment: This problem is trivial and uninteresting if there are no constraints on $x$ beyond nonnegativity. So I'm going to assume we're missing some context here---some additional constraints that relate the values of $x$ to each other somehow. And unfortunately, if that is the case, even the strictly increasing condition offered by @Kuifje below is no guarantee.

Comment: Also, are you sure by "min", you do not mean "arg min"?

Comment: yes it is argmin. I dont know who edited the question to make it min... I used the word equivalent in the original question

Answer (score 1):

If variables $x_i$ are independent, all you need is $f$ to be a strictly increasing function.

Generally, for any function $f = g \circ h$, if $g$ is strictly increasing, then $f$ and $h$ have the same variations. In particular, $f$ and $g$ have the same optimums.

To understand where this comes from (this is not a proof), consider the mono-variable case. The derivative of $f$ with respect to variable $x$ is
$$
f'(x)=g'(h)\cdot h'(x)
$$
Since $g$ is strictly increasing, $g'(h)>0$, so $f'(x)$ and $h'(x)$ are simultaneously positive or negative, i.e., $f(x)$ and $h(x)$ have the same variations. The same logic holds in the multi-variable case, but you work with jacobian matrices.

Comment: yes they are independent. can you explain it to me briefly? thank you very much. that is a great news that f only needs to be increasing.

Comment: thank you. i know it is very basic but i just happen to have no knowlesge on this theorem. is there any link to the proof of this that you can point me to?

Comment: The derivative of a composition of functions is known as the chain rule: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule. The rest is a consequence of this rule.

Comment: what is "variation" and what is the relationship between "variation" and optimum ? thank you for leading me there

Comment: By variation I mean increasing or decreasing.

Comment: Alas, if there are _any_ constraints on $x$ besides simple nonnegativity, this condition isn't sufficient. I've voted you up but I think we're missing context.

Comment: @Michael Grant. Hi sorry about the earlier confusion. I added some context. Could you look at it now and see what kind of function f has to be?